# undefined reference to property_get

Tags: android, android-ndk

My aims to do fine tuning to find proper thread priority.

The thread I concern is located in under /hardware/my_company/codec/openmax_il/

I modified 2 files

1. Android.mk

   Add "$(TOP)/system/core/include" in the list of LOCAL_C_INCLUDES as below

   ```
   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \

       blur blur blur
       $(TOP)/hardware/my_company/camera/v4l2_camerahal \
       $(TOP)/system/core/include
   ```
2. In my source file.

   ```
   #include <cutils/properties.h>

   int componentInit(blur blur blur)
   {
      int ret = 0;

      blur blur blur

      // To find proper thread priority
      char value[92];
      property_get("omx.video_enc.priority", value, "0");
      setVideoEncoderPriority(atoi(value));

      return ret;
   }
   ```

But, I encountered the linking error of

```
 error: undefined reference to 'property_get'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If anyone helps this, it would be good to me. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You have to add in your source file

```
#include <cutils/properties.h>
```

and link to libcutils in your android.mk:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want to use `__system_property_get()`, which is defined in `<sys/system_properties.h>`. From that header:

```
/* Look up a system property by name, copying its value and a
** \0 terminator to the provided pointer.  The total bytes
** copied will be no greater than PROP_VALUE_MAX.  Returns
** the string length of the value.  A property that is not
** defined is identical to a property with a length 0 value.
*/
int __system_property_get(const char *name, char *value);
```

This signature is not exactly what you're looking to use, since you have a default value in the event the property isn't defined. Since `__system_property_get()` returns 0 in the event of the property not being defined, you can easily supplement this yourself.

Here is how I've solved the issue in my own native code, and it works well for me (though it is lacking buffer overflow checking, which would be a better solution):

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>
int android_property_get(const char *key, char *value, const char *default_value)
{
    int iReturn = __system_property_get(key, value);
    if (!iReturn) strcpy(value, default_value);
    return iReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add:

```
 #include <cutil/properties.h>
```

and link the libcutils in Andorid.mk

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils`
```