# How does android read "android.os.Build.TAGS"

Tags: android, c

Can anyone tell how does android framework read android.os.Build.TAGS. Is there a way that I can read the tages using C language. As I have read the tags and do something in native C code...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use

```
property_get("ro.build.tags")
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13357240/1109425)

Comment: Bingo.. thnx for the help. But how do I know ro.build.tags relates to android.os.Build.tags. Is there any map that I can know..

Comment: You could check the [source](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Build.java) not sure if it is documented anywhere

Comment: Is there any way in C that I can get the list of packages. Because I have to find for some packages.. I can't use PackageManager(Java) to get the list of packages.

Comment: i dont think there are any, but you could run the command **pm list packages** and get the list